# Converting tree view to byte[], then back again

Tags: c#, serialization, treeview, deserialization

I'm trying to convert a treeview to a byte array and then back again. So far when the form loads, it will load the structure of my documents. Then as far as I know, it will convert it to a byte array and back but I'm not sure how to convert the byte array back to the tree view.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        ListDirectory(treeView1, filepath);
    }

    private static void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();

        var stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        var rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var node = new TreeNode(rootDirectory.Name) { Tag = rootDirectory };
        stack.Push(node);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentNode = stack.Pop();
            var directoryInfo = (DirectoryInfo)currentNode.Tag;

            foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                var childDirectoryNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name) { Tag = directory };
                currentNode.Nodes.Add(childDirectoryNode);
                stack.Push(childDirectoryNode);
            }

            foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                currentNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        }

        treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
    }

    private Byte[] SerilizeQueryFilters()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach(TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            list.Add(node);
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, list);
            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

    private void DeSerilizeQueryFilters(byte[] items)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(items, 0, items.Length);
                ms.Position = 0;
                _list = bf.Deserialize(ms) as List<TreeNode>;
                treeView2.Nodes.AddRange(_list.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = SerilizeQueryFilters();
        DeSerilizeQueryFilters(data);
    }
}
```

So the bit that's throwing an error at the moment is

```
_list = bf.Deserialize(ms) as List<TreeNode>;
```

and I get this error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do not use Binary Formatter. => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete

Comment: You don't want to convert the tree view to a byte array, or any other format. UI controls are just *views* of *data*. Classes like `TreeNode` aren't designed to be serialized, as they contain UI context that it makes no sense to serialize. Separate the data from the control and figure out how to serialize just the data.

Comment: @Fildor I know you said BinaryFormatter is the worst but eventually it's going to be sent over TCP so I think it has to be.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Fildor so what do you recommend me?

Comment: => [Recommended Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete#recommended-action)

Comment: Or use something that versions unbound from the .NET runtime, like Protobuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easy using the recommendation of @Fildor I stop using `BinaryFormatter` and now I use `JSON` and using the recommendation of @madreflection
I create a custom class to save the data of the `TreeNode`.

**Custom TreeNode Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TreeViewStuff
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int id;
        public string text = "";
        public int parentId = 0;
        public bool cheked = false;
    }
}
```

**Deserialize/Serialize TreeView Class**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeViewStuff
{
    public class TreeviewPersist
    {

        public static string strJson;
        private static TreeView treeView_;

        static public string ToJson(TreeView treeView)
        {
            List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();

            foreach(TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes) 
            {
                SerializeTree(nodes, node);
            }

            nodes.RemoveAt(0);

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodes);
        }

        public delegate void FunctionDelegate();

        public static void FromJson(string strJson_, TreeView treeView)
        {
            strJson = strJson_;
            treeView_ = treeView;

            treeView.BeginInvoke(new FunctionDelegate(FromJson));
        }

        private static void FromJson()
        {
            treeView_.Nodes.Clear();

            List<Node> nodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Node>>(strJson);

            foreach(Node node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.parentId == 0)
                {
                    TreeNode treeNode = treeView_.Nodes.Add(node.text);
                    treeNode.Name = $"{node.id}";
                    treeNode.Checked = node.cheked;
                }
                else
                {
                    TreeNode[] foundNodes = treeView_.Nodes.Find($"{node.parentId}", true);
                    if (foundNodes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        TreeNode treeNode = foundNodes[0].Nodes.Add(node.text);
                        treeNode.Checked = node.cheked;
                        treeNode.Name = $"{node.id}";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static private void SerializeTree(List<Node> nodes, TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            Node node = new Node();

            bool suces = Int32.TryParse(treeNode.Name, out node.id);

            TreeNode parent = treeNode.Parent;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                suces = Int32.TryParse(parent.Name, out node.parentId);
            }
            else
            {
                node.parentId = 0;
            }

            node.text = treeNode.Text;
            node.cheked = treeNode.Checked;

            nodes.Add(node);

            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                SerializeTree(nodes, tn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Directories/Files to TreeView Method**

```
private static void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();

    int id = 1;

    var stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    var rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var node = new TreeNode(rootDirectory.Name) { Tag = rootDirectory };
    stack.Push(node);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentNode = stack.Pop();
        var directoryInfo = (DirectoryInfo)currentNode.Tag;
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            var childDirectoryNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name) { Tag = directory };
            childDirectoryNode.Name = $"{id++}";
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(childDirectoryNode);
            stack.Push(childDirectoryNode);
        }
        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(file.Name);
            treeNode.Name = $"{id++}";
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        }

    }

    treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

To make this work each `TreeNode` needs to have a `Unique Id` that is going to be saved in the name of the `TreeNode` as I do in the Directories/Files to TreeView Method. Thanks @Fildor and @madreflection for your help!